# Linking separate binaries

Tags: c, linker, ld

Say I have two executables that need to be loaded in the same address space, at different addresses. I want to keep the two executables as separate files, but allow one to call functions from another.

For example, if executable A, which has to be loaded at 0x1000, contains a function `void foo()` at 0x1ABC and executable B, loaded at 0x2000, calls `foo()`, I want that to end up as `call 0x1ABC` in executable B.

The reason I need this is for toy OS. I need my bootloader to know where my interrupt handler is and where kernel code starts. I might be able to squeeze the whole thing into one file, but I'd rather not.

At the moment I solve the problem by manually loading needed functions at "nice" addresses and  manually writing the jumps to them. It works, but, needles to say, it is suboptimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found it. In ld linker scrips there is a `(NOLOAD)` option for sections that can be assumed to already reside in memory.

For example, if `foo.o` wants to call a function from `bar.o`, the linker script to build `foo.bin` without including any code from `bar.o` in it would have

```
SECTIONS
{ 
  . = 0x1000;
  foo : { foo.o (*) }

  . = 0x2000;
  bar (NOLOAD) : { bar.o (*) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to provied the addresses of the function over a second path. This could be a file for example, or a fixed memory address. If you have the full control over the system, the last version should work well.